# Formula for lens periscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, instrument

I want to build a periscope.

To my great surprise even after intense googling I could find little relevant information about periscopes anywhere on the internet.

Let's say I want to build a periscope with height ***h***, apparent height ***h1***, diameter ***d*** and viewing angle ***v***. What other variables should I define for a periscope?

[image]
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periscope).

I am looking for a formula/manual/recipe for calculating the lenses and distances as well as any practical advice on building a DIY periscope.

Thanks.

Comment: I think u don't actually require a lens for DIY periscope it will work fine without lens, i had made one 4 my bro without any lens

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is build the combination is a terrestrial refracting telescope and a periscope.

As the design of the periscope is straight forward so you need to look up terrestrial refracting telescope to get some idea of the linear dimensions between lenses and the focal length of the lenses. 
There is [some simple theory given at this website](http://www.a-levelphysicstutor.com/optics-telescs.php).

A search of the internet will give you construction details and suggestions for dimensions.

Comment: would it be possible to build a reflecting periscope (using mirrors instead of lenses)?

Comment: If you do not want any magnification then you can use just mirrors or prisms.

Comment: no magnification is required but I want a large viewing angle, is it the same thing or something else?

Comment: The longer the periscope the smaller will be the viewing angle.  The larger The large the aperture the larger the viewing angle.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The submarine periscope certainly does not feel like looking into a long pipe with a tiny hole at the end.

Comment: I think that a submarine periscope has a few lenses as well as some prisms inside it?

Comment: @daniel.sedllacek Binoculars shrink the light path using prisms rather than reflecting periscope mirrors right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two prisms are planar reflectors, there's no significant effect from them. If you do your refractor-telescope calculations by measuring the distances along the center of the light path, including the right angle bends, it should all work out. Then you put in the right-angle, planar reflectors (prisms or mirrors) and get the direction you want as an effect independent from magnification and focus.  The only other issue of the reflectors is their width relative to the angle of view you want to get.  But again, this is independent of the right angles - it's still just distance and width of the tube.