# The middle lens in periscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Came across this question which has the example design of periscopes from wiki, [Formula for lens periscope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278940/),

[image]

what does the lens b (left) or b1 (right) do? It seems light converge at the center and then go on to diverge as they would if the lens were not there, so why are they there?

Comment: If you follow your links back to Wikipedia, you see that b and b1 are [Field lenses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YmFHAFYwmY). That Wikipedia article isn't very helpful. This one from the RP Photonics Encylopedia is better - [Field Lenses](https://www.rp-photonics.com/field_lenses.html)

Comment: Got it thanks!! If you want to write this as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you. Glad it helped. But since this is just a link and not my own answer, I will leave it as a comment.